# RegisterClass failing

Tags: c++, windows

I am making a simple Windows program, but for some reason `RegisterClass` is returning `FALSE`, and I'm not sure why.

I set the `lpszClassName`, `hInstance`, and `lpfnWndProc` members of my `WNDCLASS` structure.

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

template<typename T>
class BaseWindow {
public:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT umsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
        T* pThis = NULL;
        if (umsg == WM_NCCREATE) {
            CREATESTRUCT* pCreate = (CREATESTRUCT*)lparam;
            pThis = (T*)pCreate->lpCreateParams;
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pThis);
            pThis->m_hwnd = hwnd;
        } else {
            pThis = (T*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
        }
        return pThis->HandleMessage(umsg, wparam, lparam);
    }
    HWND m_hwnd;
    BOOL cls_state = FALSE;
    BOOL Init() {
        WNDCLASS wc;
        wc.lpszClassName = ClassName();
        wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        wc.lpfnWndProc = T::WndProc;

        return RegisterClass(&wc);

    }
    HWND Create(const char* szWindowName, DWORD dwStyle) {
        if (cls_state == FALSE) {
            if (!Init()) {
                MessageBox(NULL, _T("Init Failed. :("), _T("Error!"), MB_OK);
            }
            cls_state = TRUE;
        }
        return m_hwnd = CreateWindow(ClassName(), szWindowName, dwStyle, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), this);
    }
    const char* ClassName() { return _T("BaseWindow Class"); }
};

class MainWindow : public BaseWindow<MainWindow> {
public:
    LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        return DefWindowProc(m_hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    const char* ClassName() { return _T("MainWindow Class"); }
};

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow) {


    MainWindow win;
    win.Create(_T("Mush!"), 0);

    ShowWindow(win.m_hwnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

### EDIT

I was literally doing everything wrong. (I'm not going to list what, just look at the answers). As you can see, I am pretty new to the windows api.

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return after the failed `RegisterClass()` call?

Comment: You left so much of the WNDCLASS uninitialized

Comment: I highly recommend not using the Windows API for GUI's.  Instead, use a framework like wxWidgets or Qt.

Comment: How much of WNDCLASS do I need initialized?

Comment: Look at the documentation. Every field is used. None of the fields is documented as "this member is used only when..."

Comment: @marcthird *I am making a simple Windows program* -- 1) If you are going to embark on using the Windows API, you should be using examples that already work properly, and from there, adjust the already working program.  Don't try and simply read WinAPI documentation and cobble together a program on your own.  2) If you are going to write a C++ wrapper around a complex API such as WinAPI, you **must** know the API already to accomplish this.  This not only is the case for the Windows API, but any API that you may want to wrap into a C++ class.

Comment: `GetLastError` is returning 1400

Comment: 1400 is ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE

Comment: @marcthird -- [Your first Windows Program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program).  That example shows the `WNDCLASS` being set to zero.

Comment: I was trying to implement [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/basewindow-sample), but the code didn't work so I wrote my own

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your code:

1. You should *always* zero out Win32 API structs before you fill them with data, eg:

   `WNDCLASS wc = {};`

   That way no fields are left uninitialized.  In the Win32 API, sometimes struct fields are optional (and when they are, they are documented accordingly), but usually they are not. That is certainly true with `WNDCLASS`.  There are a lot of `WNDCLASS` fields you are not assigning any values to, which will cause *undefined behavior* inside of `RegisterClass()` and `CreateWindow()`.
2. `RegisterClass()` can't fail with `ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE` as you claim - but `CreateWindow()` can. If you think it is `RegisterClass()` reporting the error, then you are probably calling `GetLastError()` in the wrong place (but you did not show that in your code).

   Note that `WM_NCCREATE` is *not* the 1st message that a window can receive, so your `WndProc()` needs to handle the possibility that `pThis` may still be `NULL` when you try to call `pThis->HandleMessage()`, thus leading to more *undefined behavior*.  In this case, you are likely passing an invalid `HWND` to `DefWindowProc()`, which causes it to fail, thus causing `CreateWindow()` to fail.
3. You did not declare `BaseWindow::ClassName()` as `virtual`, so `MainWindow::ClassName()` cannot override it, thus `Init()` and `Create()` will *always* call `BaseWindow::ClassName()` only, never `MainWindow::ClassName()`.
4. You are passing `this` as a `BaseWindow*` to `CreateWindow()`, but then in `WndProc()` you are casting `lpCreateParams` directly to `T*` (`MainWindow*`). That is an illegal cast. You need to cast `lpCreateParams` to the same type that you gave to `CreateWindow()` (`BaseWindow*`) before you can then cast it to `T*`, eg:

   `pThis = (T*) (BaseWindow*) pCreate->lpCreateParams;`
5. You are misusing the `_T()` macro.

With that said, try this instead:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class BaseWindow {
public:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT umsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
        T* pThis;
        if (umsg == WM_NCCREATE) {
            CREATESTRUCT* pCreate = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lparam);
            pThis = static_cast<T*>(static_cast<BaseWindow*>(pCreate->lpCreateParams));
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pThis));
            pThis->m_hwnd = hwnd;
        } else {
            pThis = reinterpret_cast<T*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
        }
        if (pThis) return pThis->HandleMessage(umsg, wparam, lparam);
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    HWND m_hwnd = nullptr;
    bool cls_state = false;

    void Init() {
        WNDCLASS wc = {};
        wc.lpszClassName = ClassName();
        wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
        wc.lpfnWndProc = T::WndProc;

        if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            if (err != ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Init Failed, Error " + std::to_string(err));
            }
        }
    }

    HWND Create(const TCHAR* szWindowName, DWORD dwStyle) {
        if (!cls_state) {
            Init();
            cls_state = true;
        }
        m_hwnd = CreateWindow(ClassName(), szWindowName, dwStyle, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), this);
        if (!m_hwnd) {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            throw std::runtime_error("Create Failed, Error " + std::to_string(err));
        }
        return m_hwnd;
    }

    virtual const TCHAR* ClassName() { return _T("BaseWindow Class"); }
};

class MainWindow : public BaseWindow<MainWindow> {
public:
    LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        return DefWindowProc(m_hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    const TCHAR* ClassName() override { return _T("MainWindow Class"); }
};

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow) {
    try {
        MainWindow win;
        win.Create(_T("Mush!"), 0);

        ShowWindow(win.m_hwnd, nCmdShow);

        MSG msg;
        while (GetMessage (&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        return msg.wParam;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, ex.what(), "Error!", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Now, that being said, your program will not exit when you close the window, because you are not doing anything to break the message loop.

When the window is closed, it will send you a `WM_CLOSE` message, which you are passing to `DefWindowProc()`, which handles it by calling `DestroyWindow()` on the window.

`DestroyWindow()` will send you a `WM_DESTROY` message, which you are also passing to `DefWindowProc()`, but it doesn't do anything with that message.  So, the message loop keeps running, but with no window to service anymore.

So, you have to break the message loop manually, ie by calling `PostQuitMessage()` when you receive `WM_DESTROY`.  That will generate a `WM_QUIT` message in the message queue, which will cause `GetMessage()` to return 0 when it reaches that message, thus breaking the message loop.

```
class MainWindow : public BaseWindow<MainWindow> {
public:
    LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        if (uMsg == WM_DESTROY) {
            PostQuitMessage(0); // <-- ADD THIS
        }
        return DefWindowProc(m_hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    ...
};
```

Comment: I was calling `GetLastError()` after `win.Create()`

Comment: I had to use `win.Create(_T("Mush!"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW)`, otherwise the title bar won't respond

Comment: the message loop isn't breaking after I close the window

Comment: Of course not, because you are not doing anything yet to break the message loop. I have updated my example to demonstrate this. Also see [Your First Windows Program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) on MSDN.